# Processing data swapped over files BASH

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, batch-processing

First, I would like to apologize for my *extremely* basic knowledge about coding. Then I hope that I will be able to express myself correctly about my issue. Do no hesitate to ask for further clarifications or anything else...

I'm encountering troubles postprocessing data...

My goal is to recombine data which were swapped.

EDIT : here is a .rar folder containing my test example which works and the one that I try to make working... (do not be afraid by the time it requires to process the data)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AEPUc8haT5_Z3LR3jnZZlpyfxhdDwwo6/view?usp=sharing

EDIT 2 : Here is what I expect on paper (Its my TestReorder3OK folder in my rar archive)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tasgq.jpg)

EDIT 3 : MINIMAL COMPLETE EXAMPLE

**Script :**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Definir le nombre de replica

NP=3
NP1=$[NP-1]
rm torder*
for repl in `seq 0 $NP1`
do
   echo $repl
# colle la colonne 2 du fichier .lammps dans un fichier rep_0, puis dans la seconde boucle, la colonne 3 dans rep_1, etc.  
   awk -v rep=$repl '{r2=rep+2;print $r2}'  < log.lammps  > rep_$repl
   i=0
   j=0
# cree une boucle dans la boucle
   for a in `cat rep_$repl`
   do
        i=$[i+1]
    j=$[j+3]
        head -$i screen.$repl.temp | tail -1  >> torder.$a
    head -$j ccccd2_H_${repl}_col.bak2 | tail -3 >> ccccd2_H_${a}_temp_col.bak2
   done
done
```

**log.lammps file**

```
1 0 1 2
2 1 0 2
3 1 2 0
```

Starting at column 2, this file contains the number associated to the inputs below. Here is an expanded explanation :

column 2 has three values : 0, 1 and 1 ; the 0 is associated to the first three lines of the file `ccccd2_H_0_col.bak2`, the next three ones are associated the 1 and the last three ones again to the value 1.

column 3 has also three values : 1, 0 and 2 ; the 1 is associated to the first three lines of the file `ccccd2_H_1_col.bak2`, the next three ones are associated the 0 and the last three ones again to the value 2.

Same story for column 4.

Now what I want, is that every set of three lines associated to the 0 value go into a single file. Every set of three lines associated to the 1 value go into another single file, and the sets of three lines associated to the 2 value to a last file.

***Inputs :***

**ccccd2_H_0_col.bak2**

```
blank line
N a b c
C d e f

N g h i
C j k l

N m n o
C p q r
```

**ccccd2_H_1_col.bak2**

```
blank line
N s t u
C v w x

N y z a
C b c d

N e f g
C h i j
```

**ccccd2_H_2_col.bak2**

```
blank line
N k l m
C n o p

N q r s
C t u v

N w x y
C z a b
```

***Outputs :*** These are the desired outputs and the one that I get for simple test files

**ccccd2_H_0_temp_col**

```
blank line
N a b c
C d e f

N y z a
C b c d

N w x y
C z a b
```

**ccccd2_H_1_temp_col**

```
blank line
N g h i
C j k l

N m n o
C p q r

N s t u
C v w x
```

**ccccd2_H_2_temp_col**

```
blank line
N e f g
C h i j

N k l m
C n o p

N q r s
C t u v
```

This works fine on small test files (as shown here), but not on my real system. For my real system, I have the `log.lammps` file that contains 14 rows and 10,001 lines, and my input files that contain 121,121 lines (so 10,001 * block of 121 lines). It creates files 10 times larger with more data than it should.

Can you enlighten me about my issue ? I think this is linked to the difference of line number from my files containing a single row and the files containing cartesian coordinates, but I really don't understand the link nor the way to solve it...

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Please just post some concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: I added a link to my google drive in the post

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AEPUc8haT5_Z3LR3jnZZlpyfxhdDwwo6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I edited my post with my examples

Comment: My bad, I copied/pasted the names... I expanded my explanation as you suggested. I hope it's clearer..

Comment: As you can see, nobody understand the question, you create a lot of files without sample given. ccccd2_H_${a}_temp_col.bak2 , rep_$repl , torder.$a.

Comment: All the sample are in the post.. I don't understand you're remark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying do do now and this GNU awk script (for ARGIND, ENDFILE and inbuilt open file management) will do it:

```
$ cat ../tst.awk
ARGIND == 1 {
    for (inFileNr=2; inFileNr<=NF; inFileNr++) {
        outFileNrs[inFileNr,NR] = $inFileNr
    }
    next
}
ENDFILE { RS = "" }
{ print ORS $0 > ("ccccd2_H_" outFileNrs[ARGIND,FNR] "_temp_col") }
```

Look:

**INPUT:**

```
$ ls
ccccd2_H_0_col.bak2  ccccd2_H_1_col.bak2  ccccd2_H_2_col.bak2  log.lammps

$ cat log.lammps
1 0 1 2
2 1 0 2
3 1 2 0

$ paste ccccd2_H_0_col.bak2 ccccd2_H_1_col.bak2 ccccd2_H_2_col.bak2 | sed 's/\t/\t\t/g'

N a b c         N s t u         N k l m
C d e f         C v w x         C n o p

N g h i         N y z a         N q r s
C j k l         C b c d         C t u v

N m n o         N e f g         N w x y
C p q r         C h i j         C z a b
```

**SCRIPT EXECUTION:**

```
$ awk -f ../tst.awk log.lammps ccccd2_H_0_col.bak2 ccccd2_H_1_col.bak2 ccccd2_H_2_col.bak2
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ ls
ccccd2_H_0_col.bak2  ccccd2_H_1_col.bak2  ccccd2_H_2_col.bak2  log.lammps
ccccd2_H_0_temp_col  ccccd2_H_1_temp_col  ccccd2_H_2_temp_col

$ paste ccccd2_H_0_temp_col ccccd2_H_1_temp_col ccccd2_H_2_temp_col | sed 's/\t/\t\t/g'

N a b c         N g h i         N e f g
C d e f         C j k l         C h i j

N y z a         N m n o         N k l m
C b c d         C p q r         C n o p

N w x y         N s t u         N q r s
C z a b         C v w x         C t u v
```